# what type of code will contain inside JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I know the intenal architecture of the JVM upto some extent.

My question is: What kind of code internally contains in Runtime Areas (such as Heap area, Stack area, Method area, etc.) of JVM?

Whether these areas contain byte code or interpreter converted machine code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack and heap usually don't usually contain executable code: neither byte code nor native code. They contain data only (local variables and parameters on the stack, objects on the heap).

The method area contains internal control structures of the JVM. The information about loaded classes, methods, etc. This will probably contain the bytecode of each method. It *can* very well contain compiled (native) code of some methods (or smaller/larger parts) as well, that depends on what kind of optimizations the JVM does.